Google Cloud Function error 401 by using service account key
I am trying to authenticate in Python to GCP in order to call Cloud Functions.
I have set up a service account with roles as follows

and created a JSON key for it. Double-checking from the Cloud Function pane I can see that its permissions are correct (tried giving Admin as well)

However, authentication seems to always succeed no matter what
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth.transport.requests


key_path = "path/to/key.json"
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path, scopes=scopes
)

auth_request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(auth_request)
print(credentials.token)  # Bearer xxxxx

but later, the bearer token seems to not grant me access to the API, as I get error 401

Bearer error="invalid_token" error_description="The access token could not be verified"

I have tried regenerating the JSON key multiple times. The function itself works fine because I tested a public version of it and it works no problem.

EDIT
I have also tried creating a JWT as per documentation with the following code. Still failing to authorize, never failing to authenticate
import json
import datetime
import jwt
import requests

# Load the service account key file
key_file_path = "path/to/key.json"
with open(key_file_path) as f:
    service_account_info = json.load(f)

# Extract the necessary information from the service account info
private_key = service_account_info['private_key']
client_email = service_account_info['client_email']

# Define the JWT headers and payload
headers = {
    "alg": "RS256",
    "typ": "JWT",
    "kid": service_account_info['private_key_id']
}

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
expiry = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

payload = {
    "iss": client_email,
    "sub": client_email,
    "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    "iat": now,
    "exp": expiry,
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
}

# Generate the JWT
jwt_token = jwt.encode(payload, private_key, algorithm="RS256", headers=headers)

# Define the request to get the Google-signed ID token
token_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
body = {
    "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    "assertion": jwt_token
}

# Make the request to get the ID token
response = requests.post(token_url, headers=headers, data=body)

# Print the response (contains the ID token)
if response.status_code == 200:
    id_token = "bearer "+response.json().get('access_token')
    print("ID Token:", id_token)
else:
    print("Error:", response.json())


You should (!?) only need the 2 Invoker roles (roles/cloudfunctions.invoker,roles/run.invoker). It's better|easier to use google.auth.default() to get credentials (instead of explicitly referencing the key). Your code is incomplete, where are you making the request against the Cloud Function? Please include a minimal repro of your code.

@DazWilkin I'm not sure about needing only those two roles, admin priviliges overlap so it shouldn't matter but I'll try. After these tests I won't auth with Python, so I prefer to stick to using the JSON key for authentication. As per invoking the request I'm using Postman, I guarantee that the invocation of the same function works if that function does not have authentication

@davidem. I have updated the answer. Could you please check the Edit 1 section.

@davidem. I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further

@KiranKotturi to be honest I didn't understand it and I don't think it's on the right path. Cloud Functions can be secured and accessed via API keys, it's on the documentation, it's not working for some reason

As per the official GCP document on Authenticate for invocation (2nd gen) : The full URL should be used for this snippet to properly work. See example 1(Authentication examples) section in the above document.
If the 401 error does not resolve , please note that to Authenticate Cloud Function you need to have ID_TOKEN not an access token. You can refer to a code example on how to generate the ID_TOKEN programmatically as shown in generate ID tokens in the above document.
Once you set up ID_TOKEN as suggested in the documents you should not have any issue to allow your client to call the Cloud Function using HTTP endpoint.
EDIT 1:
Please refer to the Medium Blog written by Guillaume Blaquiere which provides a clear understanding on securing the services like cloud functions.

For some use cases, an API key stays a balanced security solution
compared to “no security” or a basic HTTP authentication. Google Cloud
doesn’t support this type of authentication.

You can use an additional layer like Cloud Endpoint and create a Cloud Run Endpoint gateway accordingly by following the above article and deploy the same in cloud functions for secured services.
Cloud Functions service can be reached by authenticated user with roles/cloudfunctions.invoker. You need grant this role to the Cloud Run Endpoint gateway service-account (change <PROJECT_ID> with your project ID).Try below command :

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT_ID> 
--role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker --member \
serviceAccount:endpoint-id@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com


I've also tried creating a JWT but nothing changes, still same error
